# hiding css properties from bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

it is simple to overwrite css properties in bootstrap by adding own definitions in ur custom css file.
but how to hide properties so that its effect itself is not shown.

for eg., in this `<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button">Link</a>`, the css property of `display: inline-block;` has to be removed in some manner so that it fits inside my styling. i dont want to have the display property all together. similarly for `vertical-align: middle;`

fairly obvious to edit the bootstrap.css file and to remove it. but is there any other way i can do it in my own css?

Comment: I don't really understand what the issue is. Why can't you override it?

Comment: can you use inline css???

Comment: .btn .btn-danger{display:xxxxxx} will work, no?

Comment: i m not talking about overriding. is there a way to not use a particular attribute at all??

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** modify css libs directly, because you won't be able to change the libs file after (in case of update, for example). Instead, you can as you said put properties directly in your `.css` files.

You won't be able to *remove* (strictly speaking) the property from Bootstrap, but you can change it to adapt to your styling. In case of `display: inline-block`, you can for example set `display: block;`, `display: inline;` or whatever you need.

In fact, there is no problem here ; all properties have a *default value*, and even if they are not present in the `.css` files, they still apply depending on your browser's choices. So here is just a question of *restoring* the default value, by settings youre one and sort of surcharging Bootstrap.

If you want more informations about overwriting Bootstrap CSS, Smashing Magazine has a good article about that : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/

Comment: what is the default display property to any attribute? or put another way, does the default differ for every attribute?

Comment: Default values are specified in attributes specifications, you can find a list here for example : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

You can also try the `initial` keyword, but be carefull with browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial